# Такой вопрос, как проверять содержимое TextBox на стадии ввода текста WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю обычную авторизацию хотелось бы проверять введенные пользователем данные на стадии ввода. Как это сделать?

Comment: Есть событие OnChange, например.

Comment: Спасибо @srvr4vr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через событие OnChange - но это не всегда ложиться в паттерн MVVM (надеюсь вы его используете?)

При биндинге можно так:

```
Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Логику на сеттер свойства Text повесить и вперед.

Можно еще валидатор повесить - все зависит от ваших целей, которые нам неизвестны.